# Reading and capturing the ACL

Tags: xpages, acl

I have been asked to write an application that will allow a user to select a database and have it read and store the ACL (including Roles) into a document. I haven't been able to find any way that let's you scan an ACL and capture the contents like that.

Comment: The catalog.nsf already has all acl information in it.

Comment: I completely forgot about that database. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the ACL of a database through the Database class in Java. There is a `getAcl()` method for that. Once you have the ACL you can loop through all the entries.

Every AclEntry object has methods to get the access level, roles, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to mail you this info:
Server: XYZ
Filename: e_drev\abc.nsf
Replica-ID: 41256E1B0019C95C
Enforce consistent ACL is NOT set
Administration server: None
ACL Entry   Access Level    Roles(s)    UserType    Can delete  Can create
-Default-   Manager access  [Configure] Unspecified    Yes           Yes

Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim nam As NotesName
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim entry As NotesACLEntry
    Dim entryName As String
    Dim level As String
    Dim roles As String
    Dim uType As String
    Dim rti As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator
    Dim rtt As NotesRichTextTable

```
Set nam = session.CreateName(session.UserName)

Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim askme As Variant

askme = workspace.Prompt("13","Mail me ACL and DB-info", "Select database to report on: ")
Set db = session.GetDatabase(askme(0), askme(1))
Set acl = db.ACL

Dim richStyle As NotesRichTextStyle 
Set richStyle = session.CreateRichTextStyle
richStyle.NotesFont = FONT_HELV
richStyle.FontSize = 9
richStyle.Bold = True

Dim plainStyle As NotesRichTextStyle    
Set plainStyle = session.CreateRichTextStyle
plainStyle.Bold = False

Set maildoc = New NotesDocument( db )

Set rti = maildoc.CreateRichTextItem("body")
Call rti.AppendText("Server: " + db.Server + Chr(13))
Call rti.AppendText("Filename: " + db.FilePath + Chr(13))
Call rti.AppendText("Replica-ID: " + db.ReplicaID + Chr(13))

If acl.UniformAccess Then
    Call rti.AppendText("Enforce consistent ACL is set" + Chr(13))
Else 
    Call rti.AppendText("Enforce consistent ACL is NOT set" + Chr(13))
End If

If acl.AdministrationServer <> "" Then
    Call rti.AppendText("Administration server: " + acl.AdministrationServer + Chr(13))
Else
    Call rti.AppendText("Administration server: None" + Chr(13))
End If

Call rti.AppendTable(1, 6)

Set rtnav = rti.CreateNavigator     
Call rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLE)
Set rtt = rtnav.GetElement  

Call rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
```

' create table headings
    Call rti.AppendStyle(richStyle)

```
Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("ACL Entry")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("Access Level")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("Roles(s)")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("UserType")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("Can delete")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
rti.AppendText("Can create")
Call rti.EndInsert
Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

Set entry = acl.GetFirstEntry

While Not ( entry Is Nothing )
    entryName = entry.Name

    If ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_NOACCESS ) Then
        level = "No access"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_DEPOSITOR ) Then
        level = "Depositor"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_READER ) Then
        level = "Reader"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_AUTHOR ) Then
        level = "Author"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_EDITOR ) Then
        level = "Editor"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_DESIGNER ) Then
        level = "Designer"
    Elseif ( entry.Level = ACLLEVEL_MANAGER ) Then
        level = "Manager access"
    End If          

    Forall role In entry.Roles

        If Isarray(entry.Roles) Then
            roles = roles & role & " "
        End If

    End Forall

    If ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_UNSPECIFIED ) Then
        uType = "Unspecified"
    Elseif ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON ) Then
        uType = "Person"
    Elseif ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_SERVER ) Then
        uType = "Server"
    Elseif ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_MIXED_GROUP ) Then
        uType = "Mixed group"
    Elseif ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP ) Then
        uType = "Person group"
    Elseif ( entry.UserType = ACLTYPE_SERVER_GROUP ) Then
        uType = "Server group"
    End If

    Call rtt.AddRow(1)
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    Call rti.AppendStyle(plainStyle)    ' turn off bold 
    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    rti.AppendText(entryName)
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    rti.AppendText(level)
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    rti.AppendText(roles)
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    'UserType
    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    rti.AppendText(uType)
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    'CanDelete
    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    If entry.CanDeleteDocuments Then
        rti.AppendText("Yes")   
    Else
        rti.AppendText("No")    
    End If
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    'CanCreate
    Call rti.BeginInsert(rtnav)
    If entry.CanCreateDocuments Then
        rti.AppendText("Yes")   
    Else
        rti.AppendText("No")    
    End If
    Call rti.EndInsert
    Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

    Set entry = acl.GetnextEntry(entry)
    roles = ""

Wend    

maildoc.form="Memo" 
maildoc.subject="ACL and database info for " & db.Title
Call maildoc.Send( False, session.UserName) ' use current name for to address

Messagebox "An email has been sent to " &  nam.Abbreviated , 0 , "Action Complete"
```

Comment: Thank you. While I am not interested in an email and table as it has to be in a field on the XPage that will give me something to look at to get started